# Pyinstaller issue with subprocess.check_output on onefile executable under windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pyinstaller

There is a requirement of running `subprocess.check_output` to catch the ouptupt of 7zip in my application. The simple code I am using is

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["path/to/7zip", "l", "path/to/archieve"], shell=True)
print output
```

AS expected it works well when I run it from IDE. The same goes crazy and not working after compiled in to onefile executable using pyinstaller. The other subprocess command `subprocess.call` works well even after converting the script in to executable. How do I use `subprocess.check_output` in the executable?

I use the following:-

**Windows 7

Python 2.7.5

PyQt4

Pyinstaller 2.1**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Got it solved by self. Used the `os.popen` command to accomplish the same task. For the sake of completeness, posting the solution code below:-

```
out = os.popen("path/to/7zip l path/to/archieve").read()  
print out
```